# Storing JSON object using Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, json, http, parsing

I am trying to store a session id in a variable that I need in order to make other calls to the external API I am using. I am running it all on the server side, sorry if I messed any of this up, I am new to stack overflow and API use in general.

Here is the code that establishes the connection.

```
    if (Meteor.isServer) {

  var devId = "XXXX";
  var authKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var utcTime = moment.utc().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
  var signature = CryptoJS.MD5(devId + 'createsession' + authKey + utcTime).toString()


  HTTP.call('GET', 'http://api.smitame.com/smiteapi.svc/createsessionJson/' + devId + '/' + signature + '/' + utcTime, {

  }, function(error, response){
    if ( error ) {
      console.log( error );
    } else {
      console.log( response );
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the data displayed back into my terminal, how can I grab that session_id?

```
data: 
I20160108-22:23:29.324(-7)?    { ret_msg: 'Approved',
I20160108-22:23:29.324(-7)?      session_id: '270E9528F59E40DD88F504BE63A9DC6E',
I20160108-22:23:29.325(-7)?      timestamp: '1/9/2016 5:23:29 AM' } }
```

Comment: it could be `response.session_id` - or `JSON.parse(response).session_id` - hard to tell if you are getting an object or a string as response

Comment: Where would I run that? Inside my .call? It is my understanding that I need the data to display in the console of the browser, and not in my terminal, but if I run that code on the client, won't that be a security issue?

Comment: Oh i figured it out, it was response.data.session_id

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if anyone ever needs this for something, I figured out what I needed for this. Here is the correct version for what I was trying to do.

```
HTTP.call('GET', 'http://api.smitame.com/smiteapi.svc/createsessionJson/' + devId + '/' + signature + '/' + utcTime, {

  }, function(error, response){
    if ( error ) {
      console.log( error );
    } else {
      console.log( response );
         var sessionId = response.data.session_id;
    }
  });
}
```